# How to search multiple words in multiple columns using MySQL from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to query a MySQL database with words entered from a form. I need to search two columns of the database with all the words entered into the search form. Column one is a record number and column two is a description. When searching on these two columns, I need the record number to be searched fuzzy (%t%) and the description searched with an exact match. I need the query to return all records that have all these words present in either column.

So if I search for C-101 the query will return any record with C-101 in one of the two columns. If I search for C-101 and Screw, it will return all records with both of those present in either column.

My code right now that does not work properly:

```php
$text = '';
$the_array = explode(' ', $formdata);
$i = 0;

foreach($the_array AS $t ){
    if($i == 0 ){
        $text .= " '%$t%' ";
        $text2 .= " '$t%' ";
        $i = 1;
    } else{
        $text .= " OR recordnumber LIKE '%$t%' ";
        $text2 .= " AND description LIKE '$t%' ";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM drawrecord WHERE (recordnumber LIKE $text) OR (description LIKE $text2)";
```

With this code if I search for C-101 and Screw it will return all records with C-101 or Screw in it. That is all records with C-101 in the first column, all records with Screw in the second column and all records with C-101 in the first column and Screw in the second column.

I need it to return all the rows with C-101 and Screw present together in the same row.

This needs to work if someone enters two, three or four words. Typically, they are entering only two.

Comment: Did you try to figure it yourself? Did you try to print the value of `$sql` in order to try and fix this? Do you know how the query should look like? (If you wrote it without the loop and the php code - do you know what to write?)

Comment: text2   is undefined also , ,

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:
First, create the search button as follows:

```
<form class="form-inline ml-auto" action="file_name.php">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="searchbutton"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

Secondly, use the following php code:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_GET['searchbutton'])) {
    $Search='%'.$_GET['Search'].'%';
    $query="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_1 LIKE ?  
                                           OR field_2 LIKE ? 
                                           OR field_3 LIKE ? 
                                           OR field_4 LIKE ? 
                                           OR field_5 LIKE ? 
                                           ORDER by id desc";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$Search,$Search,$Search,$Search,$Search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using full text search you can achieve this

```
$formdata = "string1 string2 string3 string4 string5";

$search_string = "+".str_replace(" "," +",$formdata);
//string will be become "+string1 +string2 +string3 +string4 +string5"

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM drawrecord WHERE  
                     MATCH ( recordnumber, description ) 
                     AGAINST ('".$search_string ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

Comment: This does not give any results even though I am searching on words I know are in the data.

Answer (score -2):

You have an error in your sql..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM drawrecord WHERE (recordnumber LIKE $text) OR (description LIKE $text2)";
```

Try this one..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM drawrecord WHERE (recordnumber LIKE ".$text.") OR (description LIKE ".$text2.")";
```

Hope this help.. :D

Comment: Not correct, $variables inside a double quoted string are valid and will be substituted.